# How to append a string with the routes in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have some routes like:

```
this.router.navigate(['/main/one/as'])
this.router.navigate(['/main/one/wer'])
this.router.navigate(['/main/one/sdf'])
```

Each route points to different component, what I need is, make a general format to call this routes depending on the user selection.

I tried  this option, first declare a variable `type` and assign last value of the routes to the variable depending on user selection.

```
type = 'sdf'
this.router.navigate(['/main/one/'+type])
```

i need this thing because in some times i load 2 routes at same time ,ie,

```
this.router.navigate(['main/one/as']).then(()=>
this.router.navigate(['main/one/',{outlets:{part2_1:'sdf'}}]));
```

so it have many combination,two define each combination is time consuming

But it gives **cannot match any routes error**.

this is my routes config ,

```
 { path : 'main', component : MainpageComponent,
   children:[
     { path : 'one', component :Type_mainComponent, 
       children:[
         { path : 'as', component :Type1Component,pathMatch:'full'},
         { path : 'wer', component :Type2Component,pathMatch:'full'},
         { path : 'sdf', component :Type3Component,pathMatch:'full'},
      ]}
    ]}
```

How to obtain a solution for this one?

Is there any option for this?

Comment: could you please post your route config so that we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Router navigate takes an array as argument. E.g.

```
    this.router.navigate(['/main', 'one', type])
```

Comment: but still got Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: